# How to fix 403 error when applying Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I created a new EC2 instance on AWS.
I am trying to create a Terraform on the AWS server and I'm getting an error.

I don't have the AMI previously created, so I'm not sure if this is the issue.
I checked my keypair and ensured it is correct.

I also checked the API details and they are correct too. I'm using a college AWS App account where the API details are the same for all users. Not sure if that would be an issue.

This is the error I'm getting after running `terraform apply`:

```
 Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
│       status code: 403, request id: be2bf9ee-3aa4-401a-bc8b-f15c8a1e63d0
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on main.tf line 10, in provider "aws":
│   10: provider "aws" {
```

My main.tf file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
}
resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-04505e74c0741db8d"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name      = "<JOEY'S_KEYPAIR>"
  tags = {
    Name = "joey_terraform"
  }
}
```

Credentials:

```
AWS Access Key ID [****************LRMC]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************6OO3]:
Default region name [eu-west-1]:
Default output format [None]:
```

Comment: You don't have configured AWS credentials on the machine.

Comment: You need to run `aws configure` and ensure there are sufficient creds in ~/.aws/.

Comment: @gshpychka @theherk Credentials are there:
```AWS Access Key ID [****************LRMC]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************6OO3]:
Default region name [eu-west-1]:
Default output format [None]:```

Comment: Can you run `aws sts get-caller-identity` in the same environment?

Comment: The error you're getting back is from the aws api. Terraform is simply trying to use your shared credentials. So it seems they are either no good or not formatted properly, I think.

Comment: @theherk Nope; I get ````An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.````

OK, I can contact IT Support who manage the AWS account. Thanks.

Comment: Double check that these credentials are indeed under the default profile.

Comment: @TattooedJoey This output you've listed under `Credentials` seems like an output of the `aws configure` command. Can you check the file is not empty? Look in `~/.aws/credentials` or `~/.aws/config` for `[default]`.